# Pool results with manage and re-start process from multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

Let's say that I have 500 queries to do using 4 process. I'd like to split the queries equally to each process, and then pool the results from these queries and then re-start the process using the results:

My pseudocode would be:

```
def somefunc(subqueries, dict1, dict2):
    # do something to subqueries and then add the results to dict1 and dict2

queries = [......]
iteration = 5
manager = mp.Manager()
dict1 = manager.dict()
dict2 = manager.dict()
while iteration > 0:
    
    manager = mp.Manager()
    nextIteration = manager.list()
    redistributedQueries = redistribute(queries)

    p1 = Process(target = some_func(queries[0], dict1, dict2, nextIteration))
    p1.start(); p1.join()
    p2 = Process(target = some_func(queries[1], dict1, dict2, nextIteration))
    p2.start(); p2.join()
    p3 = Process(target = some_func(queries[2], dict1, dict2, nextIteration))
    p3.start(); p3.join()
    p4 = Process(target = some_func(queries[3], dict1, dict2, nextIteration))
    p4.start(); p4.join()

    #get results from p1, p2, p3, p4, and then append them into a list
    queries = resultsFromPreviousProcesses
    iteration -= 1
```

My question is that, is it efficient to kill manager and then re-instantiate it (need to use manager because the result will be shared?

Answer (score 0):

i would re write that like this: call the threaded function in a loop and if the function returns some code check for it then break that loop and also to save the thread output create a global array with sub arrays set as the output, for example:

```
global out
out.append(this_threads_output)
```

to access the variable outside the thread do:

```
out[thread_number]# returns whole array
out[thread_number][value_number]# returns 1 value from your array
```

btw thread_number is like the first thread you started would be 0 second thread = 1 and so on.....

In all heres an example program

```
from _thread import *

out = []

def function(inputs): # replace inputs with your real threaded function inputs
    global out

    temp = [5, 3, 4] # replace with you functions code

    out.append(temp)
    return

while True:
    _thread.start_new_thread(function, (inputs)) # replace inputs with your real threaded function inputs
    #!!!PSEUDO CODE FOR NOW!!!
   when all threads != active then break
#!!!NOT PSEUDO CODE ANYMORE
print(out[0]) #0 represents thread 1; replace with you use
```

Comment: also the splitting thing just do like total/how many processes you want